# Explicación De Codigo

Tags: java, serialización

Hola he sacado unos fragmentos de un código, y estos fragmentos no los entiendo me podrían explicar que función cumplen ? Gracias...

1-

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2-

```
public String toString() {
    return (getNombre() + " " + getP_Apellido() + " "
            + getS_Apellido());

}
```

3-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.name = "Reyan Ali";
    e.address = "Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer";
    e.SSN = 11122333;
    e.number = 101;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut
                = new FileOutputStream("employee.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(e);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /employee.ser");
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

4-

```
public void mailCheck() {
    System.out.println("Mailing a check to " + name
            + " " + address);
}
```

5-

```
Employee e = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("employee.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        e = (Employee) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        System.out.println("Employee class not found");
        c.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
    System.out.println("Name: " + e.name);
    System.out.println("Address: " + e.address);
    System.out.println("SSN: " + e.SSN);
    System.out.println("Number: " + e.number);
}
```

Les agradecería que me explicaran que hace cada código , son fragmentos que no entiendo de un código completo muchas gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Este código es parte de una instrucción try catch. Esta instrucción sirve para capturar excepciones y así evitar un comportamiento no adecuado de nuestro programa. Se puede especificar el tipo de excepción que queremos capturar, en este caso FileNotFoundException (sucede si no encuentra el archivo al que nos referimos) y IOException (sucede cuando tenemos algún problema a la hora de una operación de lectura o escritura).

Se puede capturar una excepción sin indicar el tipo de excepción, haciéndolo de manera general con Exception.

http://leo.ugr.es/J2ME/CLDC/transjava/node10.html

2-

```
public String toString() {
return (getNombre() + " " + getP_Apellido() + " "
        + getS_Apellido());

}
```

Definición del método toString(); Todos los objetos tienen un método toStrnig definido. Lo que se ha hecho aquí es redefinirlo para, al llamarlo, devolver un string formado por un nombre apellido apellido. Esto se suele hacer cuando creamos un objeto personalizado, para devolver lo que queramos nosotros.

3-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Employee e = new Employee();   //Creamos un objeto del tipo Empleado
e.name = "Reyan Ali";          //Damos valor a sus atributos
e.address = "Phokka Kuan, Ambehta Peer";    //Damos valor a sus atributos
e.SSN = 11122333;     //Damos valor a sus atributos
e.number = 101;    //Damos valor a sus atributos

try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut
            = new FileOutputStream("employee.ser");  //Creamos un objeto que apunte al fichero employee.ser
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);  //Creamos un objeto para escribir en el fichero
    out.writeObject(e);   //Escribimos el objeto empleado en el fichero
    out.close();    //Cerramos el objeto para escribir
    fileOut.close();  //Cerrramos el objeto que apunta al fichero
    System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /employee.ser");  //Imprimimos por pantalla el mensaje Serialized data...
} catch (IOException i) {   //Capturamos la excepción si hay algún problema
    i.printStackTrace();   //Mostramos el mensaje de la excepción
}
}
```

4-

```
public void mailCheck() {
    System.out.println("Mailing a check to " + name + " " + address);
}
```

Se define método mailCheck, el cual lo que hace es pintar por pantalla el mensaje Mailing check to name adress, sustituyendo nombre y adress por sus valores correspondientes

5-

```
Employee e = null;
try {
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("employee.ser");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    e = (Employee) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    fileIn.close();
} catch (IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
    System.out.println("Employee class not found");
    c.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
System.out.println("Name: " + e.name);
System.out.println("Address: " + e.address);
System.out.println("SSN: " + e.SSN);
System.out.println("Number: " + e.number);
}
```

Esta parte de código se explica con lo dicho en las anteriores.